# My code for finding Prime Number is working fine but printing an unexpected value of 9. Explain how?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a logic to find Prime Number up to some entered value. It is working fine but printing an unexpected 9 which don't go well with logic as 9%3 will be 0 and it have to skip that number.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(2,n+1):
    for j in range(2,n+1):
        if i%j == 0 and i!=j:
            break
        else:
            print(i,end=" ")
            break

Input  : 20
Output : 2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Comment: Hint: 15 is not a prime either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You output a candidate number as soon as it is found not divisible by any other number, so for the candidate number 9, as soon as the inner loop starts with the divisor number 2, it would immediately go into the `else` block and output the number and `break` the inner loop because 9 is not divisble by 2.

You should wait until all the divisors from the inner loop have exhausted before deciding that the candidate number from the outer loop is indeed a prime number, and for that you can use the `for-else` construct:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    for j in range(2, n + 1):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            break
    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Sample input/output:

```
20
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

Comment: Your code is working thanks! but as you said that i should wait until all the cases have exhausted. Now the main thing is that in my code also the value will be printed only after all the cases are exhausted or it will simply break the loop. Just simply explain how 9 appeared, may be a sample run will be good.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've added an explanation for the scenario of number 9 for your code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a variable, e.g. `is_prime` to set it to True/False by checking if the number gets divided by any number in closed interval `[2, n/2]`.

Do not decide immediately and come out of the loop once the if expression gets satisfied using `break` as you are doing.

With a tiny change in your code, you may make your code working and with less number of iterations (to decrease runtime complexity) as follows.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(2,n+1):
    is_prime = True
    for j in range(2, n//2 + 1):
        if i % j == 0 and i != j:
            is_prime = False
            break
    if is_prime:
        print(i, end= " ")
```